# How do I repeat my code 12 times with a loop?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$date_show1 = "01-".$date2;
$date = date($date)."-01";
$date_char = date($date);

$eee2 = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT * FROM bon_info 
WHERE date_day = '$date' AND creditcart != '8' AND creditcart != '6' AND 
kassa_id = '$kassa_id'") or die(mysqli_error());
$num1 = mysqli_num_rows($eee2);
```

I tried the following script with a while loop but how can i also change the names of the variables also like

```
$date_show1 ..2 ..3 ..4 ..5 ..6 ..7 ..8 ..9 ..10 ..11 ..12

$num1 $num2 $num3......
```

Comment: Please explain more. What exactly is it you want? Where does your current script fail you? etc. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: pass the values in an array like $date_show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what you ask, apart from the numerating variables. You can use an array for that:

```
$variable[0] = 123;
$variable[1] = 123;
$variable[2] = 123;
$variable[3] = 123;

for($i=0;$i<=3; $i++){
    echo $variable[$i];
}
```

---

Better usage for this would be a foreach. Imagine you unset value 2, the $i will echo a blank echo, because it doesn't exist. Waste over effort, therefor:

```
foreach($variable as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.' = '.$value;
}
```

That method also supports non-digit keys (like `['name']` and `['id']`)

Answer (score 0):

You can concat a variable to make a variable name like that:

```
<?php

$my_date_var = "date_show1";
$my_date_var++; // date_show2

echo $$my_date_var; // if defined will echo variable $date_show2
```

Comment: Though this is not wrong, I would not recommend this method. An array will be better in the long run, maintanability and readability will increase a lot more, specially to someone new to the code. But again, it's not wrong.

Comment: Yep, he asked a question, I answered it. It's not a bad way to do thing but you're definitely right, it's very bad for readability.